# Is Google Nearby API free to use? If so, what if you exceed 8,640,000 daily limit?

Tags: audio, google-api, google-nearby

I am building a google application using google nearby and there is a possibility that I might go live on production with it. Since I couldn't find support email for google nearby, does anyone know if Google Nearby is free to use? It looks like the daily limit is 8,640,000. What happens if you exceed that limit? Is there a premium package where I could pay to obtain higher daily limit?

Secondly, does anyone know a better ultrasonic sound based communication api than google nearby?

Comment: 8,640,000 units of what?

Comment: Queries per day

Comment: You will get better answers if you are more specific. Are you talking about Nearby Messaging, Nearby Notifications, or possibly even Nearby Connections? Can you give a reference for the number that you quoted? And you will likely get downvoted less and avoid getting flagged if you are removing your request for a recommendation, that's against the SO rules I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are right. Daily limit for Nearby APIs is 8640000. If you require more, you can apply for increase in quota. You can do this in your Google Project Console under Quotas section in Nearby API. An edit icon is provided near to daily quotas section and it will give you the option to apply for more quota limit.

Comment: Hello. Is there a way to reduce the amount of requests? we're trying it out locally and it reaches around 7000 reqs between two users. Like that we're going to quickly exceed the limit.